# Navbar list alignment issues in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

```
        <div class="container"> <!--main div-->
            <div>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
                    <a href="https://wwww.kidsedge.in" class="navbar-brand"><img id="logo" src="logo_white_background.jpg"></img></a>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav list-unstyled">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <button><a href="#" class="nav-link">Login</a></button><!--Login Link-->
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item ml-2">
                            <button><a href="#" class="nav-link">Explore Live Experiments</a></button><!--Current Available Live Courses Link-->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

This code works fine to give me the desired navbar. However the login and the explore experiments button don't align to the right. In Spite of trying to add mr-auto and mr-right to the ul. Tried doing custom css align right but no response. How do i make the two buttons go the right of the nav bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check the below code? Hope it will work for you. If you add bootstrap 4 then it's working fine and you want to set the button in the same line then you have to add `flex-direction` in `.navbar-nav` so it's work as per your requirement.

Please refer to this link: https://jsfiddle.net/yudizsolutions/syakr3j5/

```css
.navbar-nav {
  flex-direction: row !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <!--main div-->
  <div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
      <a href="https://wwww.kidsedge.in" class="navbar-brand"><img id="logo" src="logo_white_background.jpg"></a>
      <ul class="navbar-nav list-unstyled d-flex">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <button><a href="#" class="nav-link">Login</a></button>
          <!--Login Link-->
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item ml-2">
          <button><a href="#" class="nav-link">Explore Live Experiments</a></button>
          <!--Current Available Live Courses Link-->
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: When i minimize it to mobile then the row goes to the next line. Any hack for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-light d-flex">
                    <a href="https://wwww.kidsedge.in" class="navbar-brand"><img id="logo" src="logo_white_background.jpg"></img></a>
                    <ul class="navbar-nav list-unstyled ml-auto">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <button><a href="#" class="nav-link">Login</a></button><!--Login Link-->
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item ml-2">
                            <button><a href="#" class="nav-link">Explore Live Experiments</a></button><!--Current Available Live Courses Link-->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
```

add d-flex class on `<nav>` and ml-auto on `<ul>`